# Limit to the column size in azure table

Tags: azure-table-storage

Though official site of azure table talks about limitation of other entities, I never read anything on column data size limitation. 
While few non official blog talks about max size of 64KB. Is this the case or there is no limitation on the size of a column only limited by row size of 1MB.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Is this the case or there is no limitation on the size of a column only limited by row size of 1MB.

We can find the limitation of property is 64KB from following official document.

[Understanding the Table Service Data Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model)

1. The combined size of all data in an entity's properties cannot exceed 1 MB.
2. The partition key may be a string value up to 1 KB in size.
3. The row key is a string value that may be up to 1 KB in size.
4. For property types. If the type of the property is byte array, An array of bytes up to **64 KB** in size. If the type of property is string, String values may be up to **64 KB** in size.

Comment: Note that for unicode strings it means that number of characters will be 32Kb max. Here is the quote from the same link:

"A UTF-16-encoded value. String values may be up to 64 KB in size. Note that the maximum number of characters supported is about 32 K or less."